# Navigation in Google Maps API for Android

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

Is there a way to navigate with the Google Maps API?
I know I can use Intent to open the Google Maps app itself, but I'm looking for this solution specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can add direction/navigation to your Google Maps app by adding [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro). This API calculates directions between locations using an HTTP request.

The quota is following:

- 2500 directions requests per 24 hour period.
- Up to 8 waypoints allowed in each request. Waypoints are not available for transit directions.
- 2 requests per second.

ANything more will cost money.